# Can't run Angular site because my angular.json file paths mismatch with what ng build creates

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, ng-build

New to Angular and after running ng build I see all the files it created in the folder I defined.

In my Angular.json file I'm building to

> "outputPath": "../DatingApp.API/wwwroot"

but the rest of the Angular.json file doesn't seem to match with the built files.

Meaning, all the files that were built in wwwroot don't seem to have the same folder structure that my Angular.json file needs/expects based on the paths in the file.

Here is what gets built, you can see it's a single folder with all files in it. And my angular.json file is looking for files in subfolders, ex. "src/..."

Why is there a mismatch and what's the propper way to fix this? Should I modify all the paths in the Angular.json file to point to the correct build files? Or is there some other mismatch from versions or something that can be corrected by updating a npm package for example.

[image]

Angular.json file

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "DataingApp-SPA": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../DatingApp.API/wwwroot",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/alertifyjs/build/alertify.min.js"
            ],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true

          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [{
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
              }],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [{
                "type": "initial",
                "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                "maximumError": "5mb"
              }]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "DataingApp-SPA:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "DataingApp-SPA:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "DataingApp-SPA:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "DataingApp-SPA-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "DataingApp-SPA:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "DataingApp-SPA:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "DataingApp-SPA"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *Angular.json file needs/expects based on the paths in the file.* ? And what is your actual issue?

Comment: I mean "index": "src/index.html" -> src folder doesn't exist! The build didn't create any subfolders. So now when connecting to localhost there are errors saying can't find (ex. favicon.ico, pollyfills.js, etc)

Comment: The first error in the Chrome console is GET http://localhost:5000/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue must be related to how you're hosting the files on your webserver seeing as the build doesn't fail.

The directory structure of your application is irrelevant to the final build, which will store everything in a single folder*.

During compilation Webpack changes any file references to support this.

Try building your application with `ng build` and serve it with something like [http-server](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server) (which you can install globally with `npm install http-server -g`).

Then you can just type `http-server DatingApp.API/wwwroot` and it should start a webserver on localhost:8080.

**Any exceptions can be defined in your `angular.json` file under `assets` which lists folders and files that is added to the final build folder. By default it looks like*

```
"assets": ["src/assets", "src/favicon.ico",],
```

Answer (score 1):

Those paths refer to files during development. When you build the code the compiler does a lot of magic. Your output in your dist directory is supposed to look like the one you showed in your picture.

Don't worry about the mismatch, this is how it supposed to be. Don't try to open the file locally since it requires a webserver to work correctly. Just use `ng serve  --prod` if you want to run your application in production mode.

Comment: I think I just needed to restart the 'dotnet watch run' command because now I can see the site on localhost:5000. Which I'm guessing is where the krestal server is looking for a build copy and not the debug copy in memory?